# How to view Epic Stories in Plan / Plan & Track / Iteration Status?

Tags: rally

Is there a way to view **epic (parent)** stories from the plan, plan view and/or track, iteration status?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will not be able to view Epic/Parent Stories on these pages.  These types of Stories cannot be scheduled into Release/Iterations therefore they will not show up on these pages.

One option would be to filter on the Plan > User Stories page by Release and/or Iteration.  This would at least allow you to see the hierarchy of your Stories to include the Epics.